# How to access this.props in child class in function that overrides parent's function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to use `this.props.childName` in child function that is defined in the parent function.
But it's TypeScript compile error (`Property 'name' does not exist...`)
If I use `this.props.parentName`, it's ok.
How can I access `this.props` of child class?

```
interface Prop<T> {
  parentName: string
}

class Parent<T> extends React.Component<Prop<T>, State<T>> {
  constructor(props: Prop<T>) {
    super(props)
  }
  printName() {}
}

interface PropChildren<T> {
  childName: string
}

class Child<T> extends Parent<string> {
  constructor(props: PropChildren<T>) {
    super(props)
  }

  printName() {
    console.log(this.props.childName) // here I want to use children prop but compile error
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are passing a prop named `parentName` to your parent component, why would your child component be aware of the prop `childName` if you're not passing it as a prop anywhere?

Comment: This is just a sample program. I can't show real code, so I wrote sample one. but childName prop actually gets passed from another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child component extends the parent component, and the type of props in the parent is `Prop<T>`, which contains only the property `parentName`.

In order to have PropChildren as the type of props in the child component you should declare it as:

```
class Child<T> extends React.Component< PropChildren<T>, State<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

By the way, you don't need to make your props interfaces generic (with `<T>`). The generics are used only when the interface can be used in different contexts with different data types.

Based on your comment, here is an example of how you can share the behavior of the parent with the child, but still being able to define a different data type for the child's props:

```
interface PropParent {
    parentName: string
}

class Parent<TProp extends PropParent> extends React.Component<TProp, State> {
    constructor(props: TProp) {
        super(props)
    }
    printName() {}
}

interface PropChildren extends PropParent {
    childName: string
}

class Child<T> extends Parent<PropChildren> {
    constructor(props: PropChildren) {
        super(props)
    }

    printName() {
        console.log(this.props.childName)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I also want to extend parents class for other reason. How can I do that?

Comment: I added an example of how to do what you are trying to do. I removed the generics from the interfaces to simplify the example, but you can still use generics if it is really necessary in your real case. Note that the type of Props in the parent is not strictly defined, it only has a constraint that it must extend from PropParent, so the child component is free to use another Props interface.

Comment: I could finally apply this to my real code and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first, you don't need any Generics in interface unless you need to use it in different places.
second, class Child should also extend from React.Component not from its parent.
so here is what might be a better code

```
import React from 'react'
interface IParentProps {
  readonly parentName: string;
  readonly children?: JSX.Element 
}
interface IPropsChild {
  readonly childName: string;
}
class Parent extends React.Component<IParentProps> {
  constructor(props: IParentProps) {
    super(props)
  }
  printName = () => {

  }
  render() {
    return <Child childName={this.props.parentName} />
  }

}
class Child extends React.Component<IPropsChild> {
  constructor(props:IPropsChild) {
    super(props)
  }
  printName = () => {
    console.log(this.props.childName)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow both, proper props definition and the child class derive from the parent class you have to include the props type in your definition:

```
interface ParentProp<T> {
    parentName: string;
}

export class Parent<T, P = ParentProp<T>, S = {}, SS = any> extends React.Component<P, S, SS> {

    public printName() {
        // console.log(this.props.parentName); Doesn't compile, as P can be any prop interface.
    }
}

interface ChildProp<T> {
    childName: string;
}

export class Child<T> extends Parent<T, ChildProp<T>> {

    public printName() {
        console.log(this.props.childName);
    }
}
```